# Google Analytics: Using chrome's console to track an event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, analytics

Will it work if use Chrome console to

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'...
```

Will this work even though the ga script has already been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The Google Analytics script replaces the `_gaq` array with its own object; its new `push()` function sends requests immediately.

This allows you to use the same `_gaq.push()` calls both before and after the async script loads.